# Updating UILabel text too often

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, user-interface, uilabel

I need to show a tilt of the device in my app. The algorithm is pretty simple, I'm using `CMMotionManager`'s attitude for calculating tilt, and I'm updating a label which shows degrees like so:

```
- (void)tiltUpdated:(float)tilt
{
    _degreesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f°", tilt];
}
```

My problem is next - CMMotionManager calls gyroscope updates approximately 10 times per second. And every time I'm calculating new tilt and calling `tiltUpdated` method each time. And when I do that, my app starts to incredibly lag. Few things I need to clarify:

1. Cause of lags is in updating the label. I defined it pretty easily
   by commenting on it. So it's not the tilt calculations (that is why I
   didn't provide a code for that here)
2. Applications also show camera output all the time. I turned off
       camera and things got a little better but still, the application is lagging.

Is there any way to optimize updating UILabel text? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you updating label on Main Thread ? ..... I think lagging can't be due to label assignment.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   _degreesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f°", tilt];
});

Comment: Hello @MuhammadWaqasBhati! Yes, I'm updating label in Main Thread, but I believe I'm supposed to update it there since I want label to be redrawn. Right? And can you talk me through what you mean about "label assignment"?

Comment: How you are calculating the tilt value ? check there if you are allocation or doing some complex calculations every time, check if there is any scope of refactoring it there ! Again check if you are doing the tilt calculation on main thread, if so then use secondary thread for this.

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev, sorry my bad, it's label text assignment. The issue is not related to label text assignment. it might be due to heavy calculation each time when you are getting "tilt".

Comment: I understand your concerns guys about tilt calculations, but I checked - it has nothing to do with lags. I commented out label text assignment, but left tilt calculations and log it to the console output - lags were disappeared. So the issue is really about label text assignment.

Comment: Do not consider the new tilt until your calculations and label text update is completed. Or you can limit the number of inputs you are handling per second.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ending up answering my own question, but I hope that'll come in handy for somebody :).

I didn't find any valuable and detailed information about UILabel performance (which is too bad because I'm interested to learn something about that), but I found an alternative, which is `CATextLayer`.

I'm creating `CATextLayer`:

```
_textLayer = [CATextLayer new];
_textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, _degreesLabelView.frame.size.height*0.5f - textHeight*0.5f, _degreesLabelView.frame.size.width, textHeight); 
_textLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
_textLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
_textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
_textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale;
_textLayer.fontSize = 17.0;
_textLayer.string = @"0°";
[_degreesLabelView.layer addSublayer:_textLayer];
```

And here I'm updating text:

```
- (void)tiltUpdated:(float)tilt
{
    _textLayer.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f°", tilt];
}
```

Also CATextLayer is kind of "animating" text changes with slight "fadeIn/fadeOut" and I like it :)